# Android :: Download Image cause An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

**PROBLEM**

I'm implement Custom ListView which have 3 different layout in one listview.

Everything work fine until the part that each item in ListView do AsyncTask

for download image and set in ImageView. While this process application Force Close...

**NOTE**

I can't provide all code here because it will too long.

However, all the process of custom ListView is work fine I have test by cut AsyncTask part out.

Please assume require data is ready in this case and internet connection is already set.

**INTEREST_ADAPTER CLASS**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder_Type1 vh1 = null;
        ViewHolder_Type2 vh2 = null;
        ViewHolder_Type3 vh3 = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        /* initiate setup view */
        if (v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            switch (type) {
                case LAYOUT_TYPE1 :
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_interest_type1,null);
                    vh1 = new ViewHolder_Type1();
                    vh1.imgHeading = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgHeading);
                    vh1.imgUser    = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgUserPic);
                    vh1.tvHeading  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);
                    vh1.tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
                    vh1.tvPostTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPostTime);
                    vh1.tvCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
                    v.setTag(vh1);
                    break;
                case  LAYOUT_TYPE2 :
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_interest_type2,null);
                    vh2 = new ViewHolder_Type2();
                    vh2.imgUser    = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgUserPic);
                    vh2.tvHeading  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);
                    vh2.tvBody     = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
                    vh2.tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
                    vh2.tvPostTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPostTime);
                    vh2.tvCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
                    v.setTag(vh2);
                    break;
                case  LAYOUT_TYPE3 :
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_interest_type3,null);
                    vh3 = new ViewHolder_Type3();
                    vh3.imgGallery = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgGallery);
                    vh3.imgUser    = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgUserPic);
                    vh3.tvHeading  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                    vh3.tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
                    vh3.tvCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
                    v.setTag(vh3);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (type) {
                case LAYOUT_TYPE1 :
                    vh1 = (ViewHolder_Type1) v.getTag();
                    break;
                case LAYOUT_TYPE2 :
                    vh2 = (ViewHolder_Type2) v.getTag();
                    break;
                case LAYOUT_TYPE3 :
                    vh3 = (ViewHolder_Type3) v.getTag();
                    break;
            }
        }


        /* initiate setup data */

        Interest_ListView interestListView = interestListViews.get(position);

        String imgHeading = interestListView.img_heading.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        String imgGallery = interestListView.img_gallery.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        String heading    = interestListView.post_heading;
        String body       = interestListView.post_body;
        String username   = interestListView.user_name;
        String userAvatar = interestListView.user_avatar.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        String categories = interestListView.post_categories;
        String second     = interestListView.second;
        String minutes    = interestListView.minutes;
        String hour       = interestListView.hour;
        String days       = interestListView.days;

        switch (type) {

            case LAYOUT_TYPE1 :

                vh1.tvHeading.setText(heading);
                vh1.tvUserName.setText(username);
                vh1.tvPostTime.setText(getTime(second, minutes, hour, days));
                vh1.tvCategory.setText(categories);
                vh1.asyncHeading = new downloadImageTask(vh1.imgHeading, context);
                vh1.asyncHeading.execute(imgHeading);
                vh1.asyncUser = new downloadImageTask(vh1.imgUser, context);
                vh1.asyncUser.execute(imgHeading);
                v.setTag(vh1);

                break;

            case LAYOUT_TYPE2 :

                vh2.tvHeading.setText(heading);
                vh2.tvBody.setText(body);
                vh2.tvUserName.setText(username);
                vh2.tvPostTime.setText(getTime(second, minutes, hour, days));
                vh2.tvCategory.setText(categories);
                vh2.urlUser = userAvatar;
//                new downloadImageTask(vh2.imgUser, context).execute(userAvatar);
                v.setTag(vh2);

                break;

            case LAYOUT_TYPE3 :

                vh3.tvHeading.setText(heading);
                vh3.tvUserName.setText(username);
                vh3.tvCategory.setText(categories);
                vh3.urlGallery = imgGallery;
                vh3.urlUser = userAvatar;
//                new downloadImageTask(vh3.imgGallery, context).doInBackground(imgGallery);
//                new downloadImageTask(vh3.imgUser, context).doInBackground(userAvatar);
                v.setTag(vh3);

                break;
        }

        return v;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder_Type1{
        ImageView imgHeading, imgUser;
        TextView tvHeading,tvUserName, tvPostTime, tvCategory;
        String urlHeading, urlUser;
        downloadImageTask asyncHeading, asyncUser;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder_Type2{
        ImageView imgUser;
        TextView tvHeading, tvBody, tvUserName, tvPostTime, tvCategory;
        String urlUser;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder_Type3{
        ImageView imgUser, imgGallery;
        TextView tvHeading, tvUserName, tvCategory;
        String urlUser, urlGallery;
    }

    private static class downloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

        ImageView imgContainer;
        Context context;

        private downloadImageTask(ImageView imgContainer, Context context) {
            this.imgContainer = imgContainer;
            this.context = context;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap getBitmap = null;
            int count = urls.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[i]);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    getBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);      //LINE 256 IS HERE

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    getBitmap = null;
                }
            }
            return getBitmap;
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), result);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                //Methods for version <16 (JELLY_BEAN 4.1)
                imgContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
            } else {
                // Methods for version >=16 (JELLY_BEAN 4.1)
                imgContainer.setBackground(dr);
            }
        }
    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
06-29 16:02:05.435    2125-2143/com.bis.org.auInsight W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5fe8180)
06-29 16:02:05.435    2125-2143/com.bis.org.auInsight E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:549)
            at com.bis.org.auInsight.interest.Interest_Adapter$downloadImageTask.doInBackground(Interest_Adapter.java:256)
            at com.bis.org.auInsight.interest.Interest_Adapter$downloadImageTask.doInBackground(Interest_Adapter.java:236)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-29 16:02:05.594    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 16.347MB to 16.000MB
06-29 16:02:05.594    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 2% free 14636K/14855K, paused 6ms
06-29 16:02:05.594    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6000012-byte allocation
06-29 16:02:05.604    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 16.346MB to 16.000MB
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 2% free 14635K/14855K, paused 20ms
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 6000012-byte allocation.
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb6695790 self=0x91c30b8
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=2144 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=153307736
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:549)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.bis.org.auInsight.interest.Interest_Adapter$downloadImageTask.doInBackground(Interest_Adapter.java:256)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.bis.org.auInsight.interest.Interest_Adapter$downloadImageTask.doInBackground(Interest_Adapter.java:236)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-29 16:02:05.614    2125-2144/com.bis.org.auInsight I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 06-29 16:02:05.614  2125:0x860 D/skia     ]
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: Wow and what should be the method to prevent this??

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapFactory` can take allot of RAM for images. It may be better to spawn a separate `AsyncTask` for every image  you download. Especially since you are currently returning only one single `Bitmap` from the `AsyncTask`, rendering the whole loop useless.

To improve the performance you may also scale the image to a lower size, but be carefull not to lose to much quality:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
getBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
```

refference: [BitmapFactory.Options documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#)

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by 'spawn a separate AsyncTask for every image.

Comment: You are downloading multiple images in your `AsyncTask`, but only returning one. Create a separate `AsyncTask` for every image you want to download, and omit the loop where your download multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

the images you retrieve is too big which means that it consumes too much space in your heap and that makes the heap overflows and so the app crashes, instead you can use [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/) to download images as then you will have the ability to control downloaded image size, compression rate, resolution, memory consumption, and many other options:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                    ISolaceContext.getAppContext())
                    .discCacheExtraOptions(20, 20, CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, null)
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    loader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

       @Override
       public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                                Bitmap loadedImage) {
          // Now you have the image in your hands as a Bitmap(called: loadedImage) and Now you can do whatever you want with it
          stream.close();
          stream = null;
       }

    });

    loader.clearDiscCache();
    loader.clearMemoryCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple images in the list, then after scrolling  memory gets Fulled & now memory can't be allocated, Also your method does not recycle memory occupied by previous Images, & it can only run if huge RAM is available. Try using [Univesal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) which have memory management using LruCache, & try running this example & modify your code according !